# iOS Google signin disallowed user agent

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-signin

I had integrated google signIn in objective-c iOS app, it was working okay, but now its giving this error for sometime.
[image]

this is signIn code when button is tapped:

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] setScopes:@[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly",@"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/"]];
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after converting to Objective-C

```
 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read")

 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

 GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()
```

Also try to signout before every sign-in

```
 [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];

 [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
```

Comment: same result with this too